# Confused with error :IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python

I am new to programming and trying to learn python.Please help me in resolving below error:
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
Not sure why i am getting this error in line number 13

```
def missingpanagram(str1):
    temp = [False]*26
    output = []

    for i in range(len(str1)):
        temp[ord(str1[i]) - ord('a')] = True
    for i in range(len(temp)):
        if temp[i] == False:
            output.append(chr(ord(i) + ord('a')))
    print(output)

missingpanagram('the quick brown fox jumps')
```

Comment: [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: When you're indexing `temp` with `ord(str1[i]) - ord('a')`, you probably go out of the bounds of the list

Comment: Your code does not handle spaces

Comment: You assume every character in your string is in the range `'a' ... 'z'`, but your input includes spaces, which are out of that range.

Comment: yeah Thanks for the comment Olivier and Tomothy.Really appreciate it.yeah i got the problem.

Comment: you should consider using `set()`